# Prevent children tags on click redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code

```
<div class="takeover" onclick=location.href="http://google.com/">
<div class="site-container">
```

And I want that onclick to work ONLY on Takeover, nothing inside takeover.

How do I do that?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: By doing `<div class="takeover" onclick="location.href="http://google.com/"></div>`

Comment: But that hides the whole div. Not going to work. The takeover div is suppose to be a full background image on the back.

Comment: Do you want a jQuery solution or vanilla JS? And, what have you tried so far apart from sticking in an inline event handler?

Comment: I'm using this on Wordpress, so whichever is more effective.

Comment: @Ishettyl that HTML is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the target is being clicked, as its children's clicks will bubble up

http://jsfiddle.net/bovuszu1/1/

```
<div class="takeover" onclick="javascript: if (event.target == this) location.href='http://google.com/';">
```

or with jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/bovuszu1/2/

```
$(function(){
    $('.takeover').on('click', function(e){
        if (e.target == this) location.href='http://google.com/';
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you edit that code to be more like the code i posted? Unfortunately I have limited JS knowledge, so that would help.

Comment: Ok, well I've added the code, and it's not working. I click the page and nothing happens. SOmething her eon my mind

Comment: Since it's in the header, should I put onpageload?

Comment: Actually I can. I've changed it to inline vanilla JS

Comment: Works great in the fiddle. Doesn't work on my page...agh

Comment: http://patriotcaller.com/5-must-haves-for-every-survival-kit/ Here's a link... Takeover is the background image.

Comment: If you inspect the element you'll see that site-container is the same width as takover, so it's site-container that you're clicking. Put the JS in site-container.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the site-container as a tag. Should I create a script like what you have above?

Comment: Yes, use jQuery and `.site-container` as the selector. Google will tell you how to add javascript to a wordpress site.

Comment: This has been super helpful. Got the alert to work, just not managing to do the redirect.. Here's the code I have:

    if (e.target == this) window.location = $(this).attr('http://google.com');

Comment: I don't know why you would use that syntax when your question shows you know the syntax to redirect a page using javascript. [How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

Comment: Yeah, I got this to work! Appreciate a lot your help. Upvote!